# Prestashop upgradation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

We are using Prestashop 1.6.4 with custom build Marketplace and many other modules. We had also made many changes to the admin files, adapters and has also override most of the controllers.

When we performed an upgrade all the js and tpl files in the admin directory got replaced.

Is there a way to restrict the modules and files that must be upgraded.

Comment: I believe only the core files are "replaced" or at least upgraded. If you had made modifications on these then you did it wrong, modifications need to take place in the override folder or the theme.

Comment: you have followed and absolutely wrong approach to modify the functionality, you must be using overriding functionality for this purpose. 

Overriding functionality is for this purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an agency certified on PrestaShop, I recommend you do not change the core of PrestaShop but passed by override, and you will not be bothered in future updates.

cordially

Answer (score 0):

1. set 444 right for this file, but this is bad decision
2. use total commander to cjmare what file will change
3. use git or some one different to install update and commit, then you can simle rollup
4. Joseph is absolutly right!